# Sympy, How to get the solution of an ODE in a certain form

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Let's say we have this ODE :

[image: 19.6f(t) + 8.0\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t)=0]

The solution of this equation normally is

[image: f(t)=C_1sin(7\sqrt{5}t/10)+C_2cos(7\sqrt{5}t/10)]

Which is what sympy will give me obviously, though I need the solution in this form instead :

[image: f(t)=Acos(7\sqrt{5}t/10 + \phi)]

With the constants being A and [image: \phi].

The goal of this is to study the dephasing of the system in question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `C1 = -A*sin(phi)` and `C2 = A*cos(phi)` (you can work this out by looking at the identity `cos(x + y) = -sin(x)*sin(y) + cos(x)*cos(y)`).

So to do the simplification, replace the constants:

```
In [19]: A, C1, C2, phi = symbols('A C1 C2 phi')

In [20]: dsolve(9.6*f(t) + 8.0*f(t).diff(t, t), f(t))
Out[20]:
             ⎛√30⋅t⎞         ⎛√30⋅t⎞
f(t) = C₁⋅sin⎜─────⎟ + C₂⋅cos⎜─────⎟
             ⎝  5  ⎠         ⎝  5  ⎠

In [21]: dsolve(9.6*f(t) + 8.0*f(t).diff(t, t), f(t)).subs({C1: -A*sin(phi), C2: A*cos(phi)})
Out[21]:
                     ⎛√30⋅t⎞               ⎛√30⋅t⎞
f(t) = - A⋅sin(φ)⋅sin⎜─────⎟ + A⋅cos(φ)⋅cos⎜─────⎟
                     ⎝  5  ⎠               ⎝  5  ⎠

In [22]: trigsimp(dsolve(9.6*f(t) + 8.0*f(t).diff(t, t), f(t)).subs({C1: -A*sin(phi), C2: A*cos(phi)}))
Out[22]:
            ⎛    √30⋅t⎞
f(t) = A⋅cos⎜φ + ─────⎟
            ⎝      5  ⎠
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, solving

[image: C_1*sin(x)+C_2cos(x) = A*cos(x + \phi)],

if [image: C_1] and [image: C_2] are known is just a geometric problem. Start with

[image: cos(x) = sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})].

I suggest asking this question in https://mathoverflow.net/. If you ask, please link the question here. I am curious about the answer.